# ASP.Net MVC Indexed Inputs Not Binding To Model On POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am trying to post data back to my controller with the following but the model list is always posting back as null.

I've checked the rendered html and it appears valid to me, but perhaps I am missing something. Never done this before and I thought if the inputs matched the model then it would bind automatically.

**Razor View**

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addons.Count; i++)
{
    if (Model.Addons[i].AddonType == AddonType.Bacon)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Addons[i].Id)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Addons[i].Quantity, new { @style = "width: 40px", @class = "form-control calculated", data_price = Model.Addons[i].Price })
            @Model.Addons[i].Name
            @(" ($")@Model.Addons[i].Price@(")")
        </div><br />
    }
}
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group" id="FoodPlatter">
                <input class="form-control calculated" data-price="30.00" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Addons_32__Quantity" name="Addons[32].Quantity" style="width: 40px" type="text" value="0">
<input class="form-control calculated" data-price="21.00" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Addons_33__Quantity" name="Addons[33].Quantity" style="width: 40px" type="text" value="0">
<input class="form-control calculated" data-price="30.00" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Addons_34__Quantity" name="Addons[34].Quantity" style="width: 40px" type="text" value="0">
    </div>
```

**Model**

```
public class BaconOrderModel {
        public List<Addon> Addons { get; set; }
}
```

**Domain**

```
public class Addon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AddonType AddonType { get; set; } // ENUM
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(BaconOrderModel model)
{
    var baconOrder = new BaconOrder();
    foreach (var addon in model.Addons)
    {
        if (addon.IsSelected)
        {
            baconOrder.Addons.Add(new Addon
            {
                AddonId = addon.Id,
                Quantity = addon.Quantity
            });
        }
    }

    _baconOrderService.Add(baconOrder);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: The model and the Razor code are not matching, e.g. where is the quantity property?

Comment: I assume this is being posted back to a controller. What object type does the controller accept? Maybe provide the controller code too?

Comment: Posted controller code also fixed the model missing quantity property. It is in the code, I must have not pasted it over.

Comment: put last two as well in hidden field otherwise they will be posted null

Comment: Just so I understand, i need to have ALL properties as inputs in order for it to post back? Is there a reason why (I am kinda curious :))

Comment: Just verified, the first 2 inputs are indexed at 0 and 1, they DO show up now. but because I need to render this in multiple areas of the form based on type the indexes map to the correct item in the list. Not sure how to fix this, I tried to index to a new list but I get a "Index Out Of Range Exception"

Comment: If you need the data to post back via the request, you have to created inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your indexing needs to be sequential starting from 0. Because you are counting i and filtering the first item is indexed on 32.

The indexers need to start from 0 and be sequential.

Comment: I think this is my issue, but I can't figure out how to correct the index, the index number is what I need to show. Setting it to 0 or 1 gives me the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your last comment:

I think the default binding model works simply that way. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx for an introduction to model binding.

You can include /exclude properties with this syntax, which also helps to reduce risks by malicious attacks.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Name")]Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

Most of the time though, I use simple view model which are only carrying the data they need.

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts and the suggestions below I realized the root issue here is the index. The challenge is that my list is grouped by a type (enum) and I render each part of the form by this enum type. Because of the place where I get the value in the main list the index is not in order. Currently I've fixed the issue as follows;

**AT TOP OF VIEW**

```
@{ var index = 0; }
```

**EACH SECTION (ADDONTYPE)**

```
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addons.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Model.Addons[i].AddonType == AddonType.BaconStrips) // AddonType is enum.
                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.Hidden("BaconAddons[" + index + "].Id", Model.Addons[i].Id)
                            @Html.Hidden("BaconAddons[" + index + "].AddonType", Model.Addons[i].AddonType)
                            @Html.Hidden("BaconAddons[" + index + "].Name", Model.Addons[i].Name)
                            @Html.Hidden("BaconAddons[" + index + "].Price", Model.Addons[i].Price)
                            @Html.TextBox("BaconAddons[" + index + "].Quantity", Model.Addons[i].Quantity, new { @style = "width: 40px", @class = "form-control calculated", data_price = Model.Addons[i].Price })
                            @Model.Addons[i].Name
                            @(" ($")@Model.Addons[i].Price@(")")
                        </div><br />
                        { index++; }
                    }
                }
```

I am wondering though if this is the best way to do it? I tried to create another empty list in my model to bind to, but it seems to throw an "Out Of Range" exception. I would be interested in knowing if there is a better way?